# Upload a blobstore file from GAE Java to Dropbox

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have a file saved on Google App Engine (Java) using Blobstore and need to upload that file to Dropbox. I have working Dropbox Java API code working, but there is an exception when using this code from Google App Engine. I have seen similar posts, but not good answers.

**Core Question : How do you upload a file from Blobstore to Dropbox?**

My code:

```
BlobstoreInputStream bis = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey);
    BlobInfoFactory blobInfoFactory = new BlobInfoFactory();
    BlobInfo blobInfo = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
    Long blobSize = blobInfo.getSize();



    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig(
        "JavaTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);
    try {

        DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/TestUpload.txt", DbxWriteMode.add(), blobSize, bis);

    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.prepRequest(StandardHttpRequestor.java:150)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPut(StandardHttpRequestor.java:83)
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPut(StandardHttpRequestor.java:23)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPut(DbxRequestUtil.java:137)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.startUploadFileSingle(DbxClient.java:727)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.startUploadFile(DbxClient.java:684)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.uploadFile(DbxClient.java:626)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.uploadFile(DbxClient.java:579)

Comment: Looks like this is GAE not allowing access to the standard Java HTTP stack? I'd suggest just making a raw HTTP request yourself (PUT to `/1/files_put/<path>` with an `Authorization` header of `Bearer <access token>`). This way you can use whatever HTTP interface GAE exposes.

Comment: As of version 2.0.5 of the Dropbox SDK for Java, you can use [GoogleAppEngineHttpRequestor](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/http/GoogleAppEngineRequestor.html), which has explicit support for App Engine's URL Fetch API.